# Command line print via GhostScript is handling printer settings differently if using print dialog

Tags: printing, ghostscript

I'm trying to print a PDF file via GhostScript command and want
to keep alive the default printer settings be done within the system environment (Windows 10 - set paper tray 3 as default).

When is done so without silent mode by using the upcoming printer dialog this works fine (even without setting up paper tray especially)
BUT - as I want the process to be done without dialog  - I've also tried it with defining the printer name within the command line.

What works properly, is that the print out happens without dialog - BUT the default configured paper tray doesn't get used - when I print silently - paper tray 1 is used

Is there a possibility to keep the default paper tray settings alive while naming the printer within the command line?

Here is my codeline:

```
gswin64c.exe -dPrinted -dNoCancel -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dBitsPerPixel=4 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -sOutputFile=%printer%" + "\"" + printerName + "\"" +" " + "\""+pdfFileName+ "\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the mswinpr2 device always uses the default setup of the printer, unless you get a print dialog, in which case you can override the default.

Perhaps the default tray isn't the one you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - I'm sure that the paper tray is set correct (tray3)

It is used when printing with other applications and also when I print via Ghostscript using a print dialog but not when I send a print job silently via command line.

Oliwan